# get source code of php file on same server

Tags: php, readfile

How do i get the source code of a php file hosted on the same server through php code?

Something like this to echo the source code of the php file named `file.php`.

```
echo readfile("/var/html/rootpath.com/file.php");
```

Thanks for any help towards this, i tried file_get_contents but that just gets the html source and not the php file's source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [`fgets()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

```
<?php
$handle = fopen('test.php','r+');
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo htmlentities($buffer);
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Assuming your `test.php` contains a code of

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo file_get_contents("/var/html/rootpath.com/file.php");
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: this does not get the source code, it gets the result after php has executed